# Live output in variables Python3

Tags: php, python, html, linux

I have this python script that I use for hosting a php web server on my pc so that I can run commands from whatever device in the house. (just figured it was easier than connecting to an ssh session; I know it is not as effective, but I use it to run scripts, not reading and writing files.)
The php command I use for starting the server tells me when someone requests for when someone visits it and shows the url. In my php & html that I'm hosting I'm using GET for the commands, So that in the php command it tells what commands are running as well as timestamp and IP addresses. I want to scrape this output so that as well as telling me that requests are being made, It will also tell me in a simple format what those are without having to read the full response. I'm using the php -S command inside of python by using the os module and popen. I've tried multiple things to try to accomplish this but am starting to think that this is not possible in python. Below is the python script:

```
import os
import subprocess
import socket

run = os.popen
get_ip = os.popen('ip r')
ip = str([get_ip.read()])
strIP = str(ip.partition('src')[2]).partition('metric')[0].strip(' ')
run('fuser -k 8000/tcp')
print('[!]Current IP:' + strIP)
print('[!]Hostname:' + socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
print('[!]Hostname:' + socket.getfqdn())

run('rm /var/www/html/index.html; rm /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html; cp -r index.html /var/www/html/; cp -r execute.php /var/www/html/; cp -r tp /var/www/html/; service apache2 restart')
print('[!]Stating PHP Server at http://' + strIP + ':8000')
pushServ = run('php -S ' + ip + ':8000 -t /var/www/html/')
```

In the above script I didn't put any methods of trying to get the output to keep it shorter, but i've tried to make the pushServ in for loops and if statements like if a command was ran then print what that was; "[!]Command_Event:'ls -la' ran from 192.168.1.1" (any ip that runs a command) I know that you can easily split the output into a print statement like that, but my problem is a not finding a way to make this happen because the php -S runs constantly until you CTRL+C which stops the server which in turn would generate no output to do this on.

Comment: Please give a clear problem statement. This is a lot of text and it isn't super clear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: PD of [processing continuous output of a command in python](//stackoverflow.com/q/8842391)

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm asking how to get output from a command that constantly runs and gives output to put it in a variable to go through it with a for loop looking for substring of that command output variable to print stuff out relitive to what my program does